# Jquery Add Dynamic class name for table with auto increment value

Tags: jquery

I have a table the code is ,

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

from the above code i want to add class="row1" in to the each tr by increment id example

```
<table>
    <tr class="row1">
    <td class="row11">1</td>
    <td class="row12">2</td>
    <td class="row13">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2">
    <td class="row21">1</td>
    <td class="row22">2</td>
    <td class="row23">3</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

how to add the dynamic class id's in to tr and the td in the table , using jquery

Comment: I suggest you use the same class for each column, no need to increment class numbers. Will be simpler for CSS and using traverse methods easy to locate elements within a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var counter=0;
$("#myTable tr").each(function(){
counter++;
    var self=$(this);
    self.addClass("row_"+counter);
    var tdCounter=0;
    self.find('td').each(function(){
    tdCounter++;
       $(this).addClass("row_"+counter+tdCounter);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/md6j2v7x/3/)**

**Edited:**
Code to set margin-left  of 1st td for each row

```
var counter = 0;
$("#myTable tr").each(function () {
    counter++;
    var self = $(this);
    self.addClass("row_" + counter);
    var tdCounter = 0;
    self.find('td').each(function (index) {
        tdCounter++;
        if (index == 0) {
            $(this).css({ "margin-left": 30,'float': 'left'});
        }
        $(this).addClass("row_" + counter + tdCounter);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/md6j2v7x/5/)**

Comment: anyway to add margin-left  to the each tr first td with counter*30

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('tr').each(function(trindex){
  $(this).addClass('row'+(trindex+1));
  $(this).find('td').each(function(tdindex){
     $(this).addClass('row'+(trindex+1)+(tdindex+1));
});});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wn8nos2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1;
$('table > tr').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('row' + i);
    i++;
});

var n = 1
$('table > tr > td').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var rowNum = that.closest('tr').attr('class').replace('row', '');
    $(this).addClass('row' + rowNum + n);
    n++;
});
```